# How does object.create work in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype-programming, object-create

Tell me if I'm wrong:

A prototype is a normal object. When an object inherits a prototype, it does not just copy the properties of the prototype, the object stores a reference to the prototype.

In Firefox, I can do:

```
var food = {fruit:"apple"};
var more_food = {vegetable:"celery"};
food.__proto__ = more_food;
food.vegetable // celery
food.fruit // apple
```

I can use the `__proto__` property to manually set the reference to the prototype object.

I can also use `Object.create`:

```
var food = {fruit:"apple"};
var more_food = {vegetable:"celery"};
food = Object.create(more_food);
food.vegetable // celery
food.fruit // undefined
```

What exactly is `Object.create` doing? Is the variable food assigned the reference to the prototype more_food, or is Object.create just returning a copy of the object more_food? If `Object.create` is just making a copy, then how does the prototype chain work if the variable food has no reference to more_food?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

> A prototype is a normal object. When an object inherits a prototype, it does not just copy the properties of the prototype, the object stores a reference to the prototype.

You're right, the prototype of an object, is just another object referenced through the prototype chain.

The difference between your two snippets is that with `__proto__` you are **mutating** the prototype of `food`. In your second example, you are just assigning a new object that inherits from `more_food`, that's why `food.fruit` is resolved to `undefined`, because your original `food` object is *lost by that assignment*.

> What exactly is Object.create doing?

`Object.create` builds a *new object* that inherits from the object passed as its first argument (it can be only either an object or `null`).

> Is the variable food assigned the reference to the prototype more_food, or is Object.create just returning a copy of the object more_food?

Your `food` variable will hold a new object, which inherits from `more_food`, there's no any copying in this operation.

For example:

```
var food = {fruit:"apple"};
var more_food = Object.create(food, {
  vegetable: { value: "celery" }
});

more_food.fruit;     // "apple"
more_food.vegetable; // "celery"
```

In the above example, `more_food` inherits from `food`, in other words, `food` is the prototype of `more_food`, this prototypical reference is stored in an internal property called `[[Prototype]]`. The second argument of `Object.create` allows you to initialize properties on this new object.

There's no copying, it's just plain *delegation* in the above example `more_food.fruit` is accesible through the prototype chain, the property lookup process is really simple, if a property is not found on an object, it's looked up again (delegation!) on the object's prototype, recursively, until an object whose prototype is `null` is found (like `Object.prototype`).

So, `more_food.fruit` is an inherited property:

```
more_food.hasOwnProperty('fruit'); // false, inherited
'fruit' in more_food;              // true
```

While `vegetable` is an *own property* of `more_food`:

```
more_food.hasOwnProperty('vegetable'); // true
```

The above example looks graphically like this:

```
  +---------------------+  [[Prototype]]  +---------------+
  | more_food           |+--------------->| food          |
  |---------------------|                 |---------------|
  | vegetable: "celery" |                 | fruit: "apple |
  +---------------------+                 +---------------+
```

> If Object.create is just making a copy, then how does the prototype chain work if the variable food has no reference to more_food?

`Object.create` doesn't create copies of objects, it just sets up the prototype of a *new object* at the time of its creation.

Keep in mind that `__proto__` is a *non-standard* feature and it's going to be removed from implementations in the future, is already being listed as *deprecated* on the [Mozilla Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/Proto), the main reason of this, and it's also why the language may never have a way to mutate the prototype chain in the way `__proto__` allows you is that it causes optimization and security problems, at the level of VM and JIT.

Comment: Thank you, great explanation! It's an easy concept now that I understand.