# How to use Object create for a prototype?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get `Object.create(String.prototype)` to function properly. But, for some reason, it never works.

## What I have

```js
let s = Object.create(String.prototype);

s.one = function () {console.log("I'm working")};
s.two = function () {console.log("I'm working too")};

a = 'String'

a.one()//Suppose to log I'm working
a.two()//Suppose to log I'm working too
```

## How it's suppose to work

```js
String.prototype.one = function () {console.log("I'm working")};
String.prototype.two = function () {console.log("I'm working too")};

a = 'String'

a.one()//Suppose to log I'm working
a.two()//Suppose to log I'm working too
```

Comment: Updated for proper console logging

Comment: `s` is just an object, it is not connected to strings in any way.

Comment: How is it supposed to know that `a` has anything to do with `s`?

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7962886/how-does-object-create-work-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let s = Object.create(String.prototype);

s.one = function () {console.log("I'm working")};
s.two = function () {console.log("I'm working too")};

a = 'String'

a.one()//Suppose to log I'm working
a.two()//Suppose to log I'm working too
```

So it would appear you are trying to create an object which has some particular behaviors named `one` and `two`. That object will also have the methods of the `String` prototype available. The problem is, the way you have structured this, there is no way to assign the primitive value to `s`. `Object.create` takes a second parameter, but that is for setting specific properties on the created object, not its primitive value, which is impossible.

`a` has nothing to do with `s`. Why would you think it did?

If you want to extend the `String` prototype, then just do that:

```js
String.prototype.one = function() { console.log("I'm working"); };

'whatever'.one();
```

If you want to extend the String class, then in ES6

```js
class MyString extends String {
  one() { console.log("hi"); }
  two() { console.log("hello"); }
}
  
const myString = new MyString("foobar");
console.log(typeof myString);
console.log("Is myString a sort of string?", myString instanceof String);
myString.one();
```

Comment: I think the `Object.defineProperties` is what I'm looking for… but it keeps throwing an error in console

Comment: @AllenMarshall Use capital `O`

Comment: It says "whatever".one is not a function

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: "whatever".one is not a function
    at window.onload`

Comment: @AllenMarshall `Object.defineProperties(String.prototype, {"one":{value: function() {return "I'm working"}},"two":{value: function() {return "I'm working too"}}});console.log("whatever".one());`

Answer (score 3):

> But, for some reason, it never works.

You added two properties to `s`, but a didn't inherited those since you are not using `Object.create()`.

Replace

```
a = 'String'
```

with

```
a = Object.create(s);
```

```js
let s = Object.create(String.prototype);

s.one = function () {console.log("I'm working")};
s.two = function () {console.log("I'm working too")};

a = Object.create(s);

a.one()//Suppose to log I'm working
a.two()//Suppose to log I'm working too
```

Answer (score 2):

`Object.create` creates an **empty object** which's prototype is the given object - `String.prototype` in your case. So when you add something to the returned result of the `Object.create`, it adds to the empty object itself, not to the `String.prototype`. `a` has no relation with `s` object.

It the second case you directly add the functions into the `String.prototype`.

You can see the content of the `s` object

```js
let s = Object.create(String.prototype);

s.one = function () {console.log("I'm working")};
s.two = function () {console.log("I'm working too")};

console.log(s);
```

So I think you want to set the prototype of `a` to the `s` to have access to `one` and `two` functions.

```js
let s = Object.create(String.prototype);

s.one = function () {console.log("I'm working")};
s.two = function () {console.log("I'm working too")};

a = Object.create(s);

a.one()
a.two()
```